# Does Google Maps SDK for Android charge for markers and showing the user's location? (2022)

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm developing an app that will show a few markers and the user's location on the map. Just those, no navigational data and etc. I'm having doubts on the pricing as the [Google Maps billing page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/usage-and-billing) shows that loading a dynamic map won't cost anything but there's no specifics on what it encompasses.
**Will I be charged for simply loading the map, adding markers, and showing the user's location in my app?** Thanks!

Here's the my function:

```
    mFragmentMap.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            mGMap = googleMap;
            mGMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mGMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

            // add Sites Marker
            final List<Site> sites = siteViewModel.getSiteData().getValue();
            LatLng coordinates;
            if (sites != null) {
                for (Site currSite : sites) {
                    coordinates = new LatLng(currSite.getGpsLatitude(), currSite.getGpsLongitude());
                    mGMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(coordinates).title(currSite.getSiteName()));
                }
            }

            mProgressDialog.dismiss();

            LatLng currLoc = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
            mGMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currLoc, 16.0f));
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hey @buzzcarla were you charged for map load in mobile SDK?

Comment: @caffmaniac No, I was not billed for loading the map and adding markers for mobile SDK. Note that I was not using MAP IDs as Google will charge you for those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in https://developers.google.com/maps/billing-and-pricing/pricing#mobile-dynamic:

Prices for loading a map using Maps SDK for Android is 0.007 USD per map load, therefore, **you will not be billed for showing a map with markers unless you are using** [**Map IDs**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/usage-and-billing#dynamic-maps).

As also mentioned there, *pricing are counted for each map load which are accrued for each instantiation of a Google map object in one of `MapFragment`, `SupportMapFragment`, or `MapView` classes on Android which are called in the `onCreate()` method.*

*User interactions after the map loads, such as panning, zooming, or switching map layers, do not generate additional charges*

You can also contact the Google Maps Platform support team as they can further explain how the billing works for Maps SDK for Android: https://developers.google.com/maps/support#contact-maps-support

Comment: Hey @jabamataro does that mean I will be charged for 
1. Loading the map (@ 0.007USB per map load) + no charges for showing the marker?
2. No Charges as all?
For me the usecase is more than half a million users as mentioned standard in google pricing doc.